# Return Hash Date Value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an hash like this: `value = {Fri, 14 Oct 2016=>58.0}`

How to return the date's value which is `58.0`?

Not much help from the [docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html).

Have tried `value["#{DateTime.now}"]` but that returns `0`.

Comment: Your first line is not valid Ruby syntax. What is the key? A string or a date object?

Comment: Hi. Nah it was just a simple hash as in post. The key is the date and the number is the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that key is a date object try

```
value[Date.new(2016, 10, 14)]
```

Comment: While that works but not flexible. Could I have something like `Date.new(DateTime.now)`?

Comment: @Sylar use Date.today

Comment: @Sylar or `DateTime.now.to_date`

Comment: Damn! I forgot about `Date.today`. This works `value[Date.today]`

Comment: I know about date#today but in this way my solution will work even if you read it tomorrow :D

Answer (score 1):

If your key is a `DateTime` object you should do `value[date_object]`. So, if you created your hash like:

```
key = DateTime.now
value = {key=>58.0}
```

You should access it like: `value[key]`

If you know the string representation of that `DateTime` object, you can always convert it to `DateTime` by using the [strptime method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)